# Embedding an external website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I used the `object`-tag to embed an external website link. It works fine on most websites. But for some it is not working. What are its limitations?

I want the result like the code below.

Which kind of approach should I use for this? I tried iframe and jQuery as well.

```
<object data=http://www.cnn.com width="100%" height="100%"> <embed src=http://www.cnn.com width="100%" height="100%"> </embed></object>
```

Comment: Some website won't allow you to iframe them, they have an API for developers to use. Example youtube / facebook

Comment: An error should display in your browser console. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy